# Создать дерево категорий

Tags: php, mysqli

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть таблица с полем category, в котором хранятся данные

| Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | Name4 | Name5 | Name6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Таких записей **более 200 000 тысяч**. 
Необходимо перебрать все category, создать дерево из имеющихся категорий и вывести на страницу в таком виде:

```
Name1
Name1|Name2
Name1|Name2|Name3
Name1|Name2|Name3|Name4
Name1|Name2|Name3|Name4|Name5
Name1|Name2|Name3|Name4|Name5|Name6
```

Количество категорий плавающее (`Name`)

Comment: а мы должны догадаться сами, как они связаны в таблице?

Comment: Добавил скриншот. Каждая новая строка - данные из одного поля category

Comment: Что-то я не до конца суть задачи понял. Если я все правильно понял - у Вас уже все в БД храниться в то же виде, что на скриншоте и по сути в этом же виде и нужно вывести. У Вас, что просто данные в БД не отсортированы внутри себя по категориям, подкатегориям?

Comment: Если вы просто выведете данные записи, отсортировав по полю с категориями (см. order by), то все само собой окажется в нужном порядке. никаких деревьев строить не надо. Если же получающийся при этом порядок не совпадает с тем, что вам нужен, то вы неверно описали задачу

Comment: Нужно отобрать все категории 1 уровня, 2, 3, 4... И создать из них лесенку

Comment: все, сегодня я уже не хочу работать ... мне плохо (((

Comment: Г-н @Mike прав - простая сортировка по полю `category` выведет то, что Вам и нужно.

Comment: Ну если лесенку, то выбираете из БД отсортированное как я и сказал и в строках при выводе на экран оставляете только последний элемент строки, дополняя нужным количеством пробелов слева (кратно количеству элементов строки). Но на самом деле задача может оказаться куда интереснее, потому что браузер просто не потянет 200к строк, он час это грузить и прожовывать будет. А значит вам надо сначала отобрать все строки из одного элемента и вывести их, сделать какой нибудь "плюсик"что бы он раскрывал одну ветку и подтягивать кусочки данных ajax'ом